# How to set up VPN using IKEv2?

Tags: networking, vpn

I would like to ask for help with setup of VPN connection using IKEv2 and `gnome-control-center` on Ubuntu 22.04.1. My employer gave me login credentials for EAP authentication and PFX file.

I have installed following packages:

- `strongswan`
- `network-manager-strongswan`
- `libcharon-extra-plugins`

and followed other instructions described [here](https://thesafety.us/vpn-setup-ikev2-ubuntu17).

I also tried to enter path to mentioned PFX file in server certificate field, but when I tried to establish connection, following error occurred (from syslog):

```
Oct  3 16:04:42 filipgl-com charon-nm: 06[LIB] OpenSSL X.509 parsing failed
Oct  3 16:04:42 filipgl-com charon-nm: 06[LIB] building CRED_CERTIFICATE - X509 failed, tried 4 builders
```

Then I tried to extract certificate and key from PFX file using [these instructions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/arl/9.7?topic=certification-extracting-certificate-keys-from-pfx-file) and enter path to extracted certificate.

Unfortunately it did't help and connection wasn't established, here you can see logs after I attempted to establish connection (I have censored the remote server IP address with asterisks):

```
Oct  3 16:12:08 filipgl-com NetworkManager[947]: <info>  [1664806328.3291] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Oct  3 16:12:08 filipgl-com charon-nm: 12[IKE] retransmit 2 of request with message ID 0
Oct  3 16:12:08 filipgl-com charon-nm: 12[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.68.123[49802] to ***.***.***.***[500] (904 bytes)
Oct  3 16:12:18 filipgl-com systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct  3 16:12:21 filipgl-com charon-nm: 16[IKE] retransmit 3 of request with message ID 0
Oct  3 16:12:21 filipgl-com charon-nm: 16[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.68.123[49802] to ***.***.***.***[500] (904 bytes)
Oct  3 16:12:44 filipgl-com charon-nm: 13[IKE] retransmit 4 of request with message ID 0
Oct  3 16:12:44 filipgl-com charon-nm: 13[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.68.123[49802] to ***.***.***.***[500] (904 bytes)
Oct  3 16:12:57 filipgl-com NetworkManager[947]: <warn>  [1664806377.9707] vpn[0x5571e22ce910,0dfa18a1-977b-43df-a423-741a25e49b91,"Test"]: connect timeout exceeded
Oct  3 16:12:57 filipgl-com charon-nm[10929]: Connect timer expired, disconnecting.
Oct  3 16:12:57 filipgl-com charon-nm: 06[IKE] destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification
```

Could you please tell me, what can be wrong or tell me where can I find detailed information so I can try another approach?

I'm sorry if I gave you too few or confusing information, this is the first question I am asking here.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1

Comment: Either the connection is initiated to the wrong IP address, or there is a firewall that blocks these packets or the response to them (could be local, at your employer or even somewhere in between).

Comment: Thank you for advice, I'm sure the IP address is correct, I've successfully created VPN connection from virtual Windows 10 with the same credentials and IP address. I also disabled firewall with `ufw disable` and there was no change in results.